# How to perform a dynamic relative import in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a following file structure:

```
mymodule/
    __init__.py
    mylib.py
test.py
```

File `mymodule/__init__.py`:

```
# mymodule/__init__.py
def call_me():
    module = __import__('.mylib')
    module.my_func()
```

File `mymodule/mylib.py`:

```
# mymodule/mylib.py
def my_func():
    print("hi!")
```

File `test.py`:

```
# test.py
from mymodule import call_me
call_me()
```

If I run `python3 test.py` it fails with the error:

```
    module = __import__('.mylib')
ImportError: No module named '.mylib'
```

I want to perform a relative import inside of `call_me` that equals to the static import `from . import mylib`. How can I do it?

Comment: Would yhis be a solution? `def call_me():
    from mymodule import mylib
    mylib.my_func()`

Comment: Not really, I would like to NOT use the original name of the package inside. In other words, I need a relative import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this,

```
def call_me():
    mylib = __import__('mylib', globals(), locals(), [], 1)
    mylib.my_func()
```

Please refer the doc: [**import**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)

Answer (score 11):

Use `importlib.import_module` and specify your package from `__name__` in `__init__.py`:

> `importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`
>   Import a module.
>
> The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative import. It
>   specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the
>   relative import to an absolute import.

Example:

```
import importlib

def call_me():
    module = importlib.import_module('.mylib', package=__name__)
    module.my_func()
```

Comment: It didn't help: `importlib.import_module('mylib', package=None)` leads `ImportError: No module named 'mylib'`

Comment: @Fomalhaut because there is no such module... you need the name of the outer module, in this case that would be `mymodule` - so it know to import `mymodule.mylib` instead of `mylib.mylib`

Comment: Then that's not a solution, because if I have to use the name `mymodule` inside, that's not a relative import.

Comment: @Fomalhaut well, then why do you need the relative import? presumably to encapsulate your module so one can do `from yourmodule import something` for this you need to know how you would like to refer to your module, otherwise it can't be done - at least not without horrible hacks